# Java synchronized problems of multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I learned only `wait()` and `notify()` or `notifyAll()`, so I have to use this function to control of programs.

This program has multiple threads which print set of some message individually, but I cannot block other thread while specific thread is running.

I find lots of way to do but I totally didn't understand. My code is below.

**LeftRightCar.java:**

```
public synchronized void run(){
    try{
        while(lock) wait();
        lock=true;
        System.out.println("LeftSideCar: "+left);
        state="Left";
        Direction();
        System.out.println("RightSideCar: "+right);
        state="Right";
        Direction();
        notifyAll();
        lock=false;
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**FrontCar.java:**

```
public synchronized void run(){
    try{
        while(lock) wait();
        lock=true;
        System.out.println("frontCarVelocity: "+frontCarSpeed+": km/h");
        Direction();
        notifyAll();
        lock=false;
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm using `lock` boolean variable to make other thread wait during execution of specific thread.

**I really want to normal result which messages are not mixed.**

But my result is like this.

> LeftSideCar: Approaching...
>
> frontCarVelocity: 40: km/h Direction : Do not step on left lane...
>
> Direction : RightSideCar: Approaching... Decrease velocity...Direction
>
> : Do not step on right lane... 80 → 70 → 60 → 50 → 40

How can I fix it using only `wait()`, `notify()` or `notifyAll()`? Above two classes are children class of `Sensor.java` which has `lock` boolean variable.

+some specific information for understanding

```
public class AutonomousCar {
public static void main(String[] args){
    FrontCar f=new FrontCar();
    LeftRightCar lr=new LeftRightCar();
    Thread Car[]={new Thread(f),new Thread(lr)};
    Car[0].start();
    Car[1].start();
}
```

`AutonomousCar` class means car which has variable sensors. `FrontCar` class is a sensor that sense the speed of front car and `LeftRightCar` class is a sensor that sense the moving of left and right car.

Because it is real-time system, it is concurrently executed which can be represented by threads in java.

Furthermore, `Direction` function is overriding function like below.

**Direction of LeftRightCar.java**

```
public void Direction(){
    System.out.print("Direction : ");
    if(state.equals("Left")){
        if(left.equals("None")) System.out.println(message.get("None"));
        else if(left.equals("Approaching...")) System.out.println(message.get("Approaching-L"));
        else if(left.equals("Too close...")){
            System.out.println(message.get("Close-L"));
            isLeftClose=true;
        }
    }
    else if(state.equals("Right")){
        if(right.equals("None")) System.out.println(message.get("None"));
        else if(right.equals("Approaching...")) System.out.println(message.get("Approaching-R"));
        else if(right.equals("Too close...")){
            if(!isLeftClose) System.out.println(message.get("Close-R"));
            else System.out.println(message.get("Close-LR"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Direction of FrontCar.java**

```
public void Direction(){
    System.out.print("Direction : ");
    if(frontCarSpeed==100){
        System.out.println(message.get("S"));
    }
    else if(speed<=frontCarSpeed){
        System.out.print(message.get("I"));
        while(speed<frontCarSpeed){
            System.out.print(speed+" → ");
            speed+=10;
        }
        System.out.println(speed);
    }
    else if(speed>frontCarSpeed){
        System.out.print(message.get("D"));
        while(speed>frontCarSpeed){
            System.out.print(speed+" → ");
            speed-=10;
        }
        System.out.println(speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]. Otherwise we are unable to help you. As-is, I fail to see how the two `Car`s communicate with each other, they `synchronize` on different objects.

Comment: Quote blocks (things prefixed with `>`) are not for emphasis or highlighting things, they are for quotes from outside sources, or - in some cases - output from your program.

Comment: Are LeftRightCar and FrontCar threads objects?

Comment: @AmberBeriwal yep they implements `Runnable` interface

Comment: @haram Can you please post the complete code of `LeftRightCar` and `FrontCar `?

Comment: I have a feeling that you have a major misconception about `synchronized`. As-is, I see no simple way of fixing your program without re-writing most of it. Maybe you should take a step back and revisit a tutorial, e.g. [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very basic flaw in the code which is related to implementation of wait() and notify() methods. Let's see how these methods actually works before proceeding to solution.

**Understanding wait() and notify():** Both `wait()` and `notify()` are object level APIs. It applies on threads that is currently working on the object. So, waiting lists are maintained at each object level instead of thread level. Consider below example:

```
public class Example{
  int counter = 0;

  synchronized void printCounter() throws Exception{
    notify();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-->" + (counter++));
    wait();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
      Example example = new Example();
      Thread t1 = new MyThread(example);
      t1.setName("MyThread-1");
      Thread t2 = new MyThread(example);
      t2.setName("MyThread-2");
      t1.start();
      t2.start();
  }
}

class MyThread extends Thread{
    private Example obj = null;

    MyThread(Example obj){
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try{
                obj.printCounter();
                Thread.sleep(200);
            }catch(Exception ex){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This example has two threads, `t1` and `t2` and one object `example`. We have called `wait()` and `notify()` for `example` object thus if `t1` executes `wait()` statement, it will be added in waiting list for object `example`. Same goes with other threads.

**Problem with existing code:** There are multiple improvements to be made:

1. **Synchronization over run method:** This synchronization won't be required as each thread will have its own implementation for run and that thread object won't be shared.
2. **boolean variable lock:** Direct boolean variables are not a good option to maintain synchronization as their could be consistency issues when multiple threads are working on it.
3. **wait() method:** This is where the actual problem lies. Here we have two objects, one of `LeftRightCar` and another of `FrontCar`. So, when wait() is called for `LeftRightCar`, thread is added in waiting queue of `LeftRightCar` object. And when it is called for `FrontCar`, thread is added in waiting queue of `FrontCar` object. So, in actual `wait()` and `notify()` calls for different objects won't help.

**Solution:**

The `wait()` and `notify()` should be called on some common object instead of these classes object. So, following code should work:

```
//lock is an instance of Object now, NOT a boolean variable
public void run(){ 
  synchronized(lock){
    lock.notifyAll();
    ...
    ...
    lock.wait();
  }
}
```

Comment: This will deadlock aswell. Both threads call `wait()`, nobody calls `notify()` / `notifyAll()`.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for the catch. I missed it because I was focusing more on explaining flaw in wait() calls. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Turing85 would we call the earlier error as a deadlock because threads are not locking any resources? It is like every thread is just waiting. Don't know what to name it..

Comment: Technically, you are right. Technically, it is the exact opposite of a deadlock since things got unlocked. Technically, for a deadlock, you need at least two locks shared by at least two threads. But the overall symptoms are the same: the program does not progress.

Comment: I just synchronized block of using `Object lock`. but I didn't use `notify()` and `wait()`. Is it fine?

Comment: @haram yeah that would be fine if you do not want to maintain order of their execution. They are used to maintain the order usually.

Comment: @AmberBeriwal Thx I got it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using lock boolean variable to make other thread wait during
>   execution of specific thread.

if your lock is guarded by ("`this`"):

Your methods are anyways synchronized, So only one thread will get a chance to execute that block of code at a time.

Comment: guarded by "`this`" is what mean?

Comment: this refers to the current object

Comment: I know what "`this`" means but it is not synchronized. That is the problem of my question. Messages are mixed.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: And You need to understand the concept of synchronization in your case it doesn't even matter because neither you are using a shared instance. Also, I didn't find any use of a boolean variable lock.  wait() notify() needs to be invoked in synchronized context and you have already put the synchronized keyword on your method