# How to print some messages before and after thread iteration?

Tags: java, multithreading

I asked yesterday about thread synchronization [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50187531/9437175).

Finally, synchronization issue is solved, but I have to print before/after threads iteration.

The code is below, it's just iteration.

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
   CarSensors=
     new Thread[]{
     new Thread(frontCarSensor),
     new Thread(leftRightCarSensor),
     new Thread(LaneSensor),
     new Thread(SignalSensor), 
     new Thread(PedestrianSensor), 
     new Thread(ObjectSensor)
   };

   for(Thread t:CarSensors) t.start();
}
```

I tried to print message "Car sensor checking..." before `for loop` and `\n` after `for loop` but it is mixed in other messages because main thread is also thread.

How can I fix it?

---

**+Some important information**

I cannot use `join` or `completablefuture`. I have to use `notify()` or `wait()`

My result expectation is below.

> print a message "start"
> main program execution
> print a message "end"
>
> print a message "start"
> main program execution
> print a message "end"
>
> print a message "start"
> main program execution
> print a message "end"

It continues for a 5 times.
"main program" means 6 threads of `~sensor` object.

**+Request for `Sensor` class**

```
public abstract class Sensor implements Runnable {
    protected Random random;
    protected HashMap<String,String> message;
    protected final static Object lock=new Object();
    protected String[] event;
    
    protected Sensor(){
        random=new Random();
        message=new HashMap<String,String>();
    }
    
    public abstract void Direction();
}
```

Comment: Why not use a higher-level concurrency API, such as the completable future? It'd make it easier for you to join/wait... Otherwise you need to call `join` on each thread in that array to continue after their completion.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I edited

Comment: can you show how you sensor classes look like (e.g.  frontCarSensor) ?

Comment: @xagaffar I added

Comment: I rather wanted to see your run method implementations

Comment: @xagaffar run method is implemented by subclasses of `Sensor` class

Answer (score 1):

I would probably refrain from using `Thread` directly in *Java* unless I am writing a concurrency building block. Also, threads are very expensive, compared to most other things you can do programmatically, so when possible, dynamic thread creation (especially in loops) should be avoided.

In the subject case a solution may be to use the functionality of `CompletableFuture` and `Executors` framework (basic example below).

The CompletableFuture allows registering completion hooks, so any sort of telemetry can be wrapped around the main logic without touching the latter.

To prevent message overlapping delegate printing to a single thread executor and have them ordered by timestamp, by the car ID, or anything else appropriate.

```
import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync;


// You can use JDK Executors, Guava Executors,
// or write your own taking the concurrency consideration
// away from the business logic
final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);

CompletableFuture collector = CompletableFuture.completed((Void)null);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    collector = CompletableFuture.allOf(
        collector,
        runAsync(frontCarSensor, executor),
        runAsync(leftRightCarSensor, executor),
        runAsync(LaneSensor, executor),
        runAsync(SignalSensor, executor),
        runAsync(PedestrianSensor, executor),
        runAsync(ObjectSensor, executor)).join();
}
collector.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the printing inside the code for `CarSensoer`

Comment: `CarSensor` is array variable of threads. Can I add printing message inside?

Answer (score 0):

If each of those parameters in Thread constructor is Runnable class, you can add print statements in run() method

```
public abstract class Sensor implements Runnable {
     //some other code
}

public class LaneSensor extends Sensor {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Pre Execution thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        // print
        // execution code
        // print
        System.out.println("Post Execution thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Structure is that every `~sensor` object extends `Sensor` class which implements `Runnable` interface. From this concept what is the solution?

Comment: subclasses of `Sensor` class is 6. but execution order is arbitrary because they are distinct threads. Your solution cannot solve my problem because of arbitrary execution. Every 6 objects have to execute as a unit and printing message has to be printed at starting and the end

Comment: Its not clear what you are expecting, but from your message what  I can infer is, you want all messages in sequence as per execution. IF thats the case, you have to run these messages in synchronous mode, by using countdown latch , async mode doesnt work for you.